# Devexpress components like in Java (JSF)?

Tags: c#, java, devexpress

Is there any components like Devexpress (.NET) for JSF?

Comment: Did you ever find anything other than Oracle's ADF suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one project we have used Oracle's ADF http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/adf/adffaces/index.html